# Coroutine that is guaranteed to exit its context managers

Tags: python, coroutine, contextmanager

I'd like to use a context manager within a coroutine. This coroutine should handle unknown number of steps. However, due to unknown number of steps, it's unclear when should the context manager exit. I'd like it to exit when the co-routine goes out of scope / is garbage collected; however this seems not to happen in the example below:

```py
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def cm():
    print("STARTED")
    yield
    print("ENDED")


def coro(a: str):
    with cm():
        print(a)
        while True:
            val1, val2 = yield
            print(val1, val2)


c = coro("HI")


c.send(None)
print("---")
c.send((1, 2))
print("---!")
```

Output of this program:

```
STARTED
HI
---
1 2
---!
```

- The context manager never printed "ENDED".

How can I make a coroutine that will support any number of steps, and be guaranteed to exit gracefully? I don't want to make this a responsibility of the caller.

Comment: Your coroutine has a while true loop.  Why should it have exited the context manager?

Comment: Well, because it's garbage collected. That's what I want to achieve, the question is how. Other way around, what could I use instead of while to still support any number of steps?

Comment: You should write the `with` statement around the block of code where the managed resource is used within and should "stay open" within. If you are `yield`ing then the resource will stay open outside of the coroutine, outside of the `with` block, and the `with` block does not serve its purpose. So I would say it's simply an anti-pattern to use `with` in a coroutine, and you should structure your code differently.

Comment: @kaya3 There is no "staying open" in the meaning of context manager to me - as it's defined by __enter__ and __exit__ methods, it's above all about setup + cleanup. But our definitions might differ.

Comment: Context managers are typically used to manage resources like files or database connections, which are "open" for some duration. The `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods are responsible for opening and closing the resource, and the purpose of `with` is to ensure the resource is closed when it is no longer needed. A `with` block which `yield`s *cannot* ensure this, because it cannot ensure that the outside code it yields to will call it again.

Comment: I believe such a `with` block can ensure this (assuming a relatively gentle finalization).  When generator functions are finalized a `GeneratorExit` is raised at the point of `yield`.  At that point if the `yield` was inside a `try-except-finally` it will be able to perform cleanup actions.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: So the issue is that when an exception is raised (and not handled) inside a `with` block.  The `__exit__` method of the context manager is called with that exception.  For `contextmanager`-decorated generators, this causes the exception to be `throw`n to the generator.  `cm` does not handle this exception and thus the cleanup code is not run.  When `coro` is garbage collected, its `close` method is called which `throw`s a `GeneratorExit` to `coro` (which then gets thrown to `cm`). What follows is a detailed description of the above steps.

The `close` method `throw`s a `GeneratorExit` to `coro` which means a `GeneratorExit` is raised at the point of `yield`.  `coro` doesn't handle the `GeneratorExit` so it exits the context via an error.  This causes the `__exit__` method of the context to be called with an error and error information.  What does the [`__exit__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7ef0673de48958bc3a75af5f152564bd2dffa8dd/Lib/contextlib.py#L123-L169) from a `contextmanager`-decorated generator do?  If it is called with an exception, it throws that exception to the underlying generator.

At this point the a `GeneratorExit` is raised from the `yield` statement in the body of our context manager.  That unhandled exception causes the cleanup code to not be run.  That unhandled exception is raised by context manager and is passed back to the `__exit__` of the `contextmanager` decorator.  Being the same error that was thrown, `__exit__` returns `False` to indicate the original error sent to `__exit__` was unhandled.

Finally, this continues the `GeneratorExit`'s propagation outside of the `with` block inside `coro` where it continues to be unhandled.  *However*, not handling `GeneratorExits` is regular for generators, so the original `close` method suppresses the `GeneratorExit`.

See this part of the [`yield` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions):

> If the generator is not resumed before it is finalized (by reaching a zero reference count or by being garbage collected), the generator-iterator’s close() method will be called, allowing any pending finally clauses to execute.

Looking at the [`close` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.close) we see:

> Raises a GeneratorExit at the point where the generator function was paused. If the generator function then exits gracefully, is already closed, or raises GeneratorExit (by not catching the exception), close returns to its caller.

This part of the [`with` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

> 6. The suite is executed.
> 7. The context manager’s **exit**() method is invoked. If an exception caused the suite to be exited, its type, value, and traceback are passed as arguments to **exit**(). Otherwise, three None arguments are supplied.

And the code of the [`__exit__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7ef0673de48958bc3a75af5f152564bd2dffa8dd/Lib/contextlib.py#L123-L169) for the `contextmanager` decorator.

So with all this context (rim-shot), the easiest way we can get the desired behavior is with a try-except-finally in the definition of our context manager.  This is the suggested method from the [`contextlib` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).  And all their examples follow this form.

> Thus, you can use a try…except…finally statement to trap the error (if any), or ensure that some cleanup takes place.

```
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def cm():
    try:
        print("STARTED")
        yield
    except Exception:
        raise
    finally:
        print("ENDED")


def coro(a: str):
    with cm():
        print(a)
        while True:
            val1, val2 = yield
            print(val1, val2)


c = coro("HI")


c.send(None)
print("---")
c.send((1, 2))
print("---!")
```

The output is now:

```
STARTED
HI
---
1 2
---!
ENDED
```

as desired.

We could also define our context manager in the traditional manner: as a class with an `__enter__` and `__exit__` method and still gotten the correct behavior:

```
class CM:
    def __enter__(self):
        print('STARTED')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print('ENDED')
        return False
```

The situation is somewhat simpler, because we can see exactly what the `__exit__` method is without having to go to the source code.  The `GeneratorExit` gets sent (as a parameter) to `__exit__` where `__exit__` happily runs its cleanup code and then returns `False`.  This is not *strictly* necessary as otherwise `None` (another Falsey value) would have been returned, but it indicates that any exception that was sent to `__exit__` was not handled.  (The return value of `__exit__` doesn't matter if there was no exception).

Comment: Do you also know why the class doesn't require `try/finally`?

Comment: Hey, I looked into that more and substantially corrected some of the explanation above.  It should now do a good job of explaining why error trapping is required for the `contextmanager`-decorated generator but not the traditional context manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by telling the coroutine to shutdown by sending it something the will cause it to break out of the loop and return as illustrated below. Doing so will cause a `StopIteration` exception to be raised where this is done, so I added another context manager to allow it to be suppressed. Note I have also added a `coroutine` decorator to make them start-up automatically when first called, but that part is strictly optional.

```
import contextlib
from typing import Callable


QUIT = 'quit'

def coroutine(func: Callable):
    """ Decorator to make coroutines automatically start when called. """
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(cr)
        return cr
    return start

@contextlib.contextmanager
def ignored(*exceptions):
    try:
        yield
    except exceptions:
        pass


@contextlib.contextmanager
def cm():
    print("STARTED")
    yield
    print("ENDED")

@coroutine
def coro(a: str):
    with cm():
        print(a)
        while True:
            value = (yield)
            if value == QUIT:
                break
            val1, val2 = value
            print(val1, val2)

print("---")
with ignored(StopIteration):
    c = coro("HI")
    #c.send(None)  # No longer needed.

    c.send((1, 2))
    c.send((3, 5))
    c.send(QUIT)  # Tell coroutine to clean itself up and exit.
print("---!")
```

Output:

```
STARTED
HI
---
1 2
3 5
ENDED
---!
```

Comment: Your output still suggests the cleanup code of the context manager is not called.  `ENDED` is not printed.

Comment: I think this still has the issue that we need to manually send `QUIT`.  We lose the common guarantee of a with block which is that it will always call the `__exit__` method eventually no matter what else we do.

Comment: @Kyle: I put the `send()` stuff in to have a way make the coroutine end and be able to test the code — it's not in any way an essential part of what's going on. The OP only states that the "coroutine should handle unknown number of steps" which this one does. Anyway, having put in it in doesn't cause the loss of any guarantees.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was hoping for a solution that doesn't make this a responsibility of the caller, but there might be none.